# Update and share variable between tests on Pytest

Tags: python, testing, hook, pytest

So, I'm running some tests that each one of them creates a variable (key), like:

```
def test_123():
    key = 'abc'
    ....
    ---- test_123 PASSED! ----

def test_456():
    key = 'def'
    ....
    ---- test_456 FAILED! ----
```

And I have another test, last to be executed, with the purpose of verify those keys. But it should verify only the keys whose test has passed.

```
def check_keys():
    # keys = ['abc']
    for key in keys:
    ....
```

Since, this verification takes too long it's better to check all those keys at once, instead on each test

So, I'm planning to create a list that should be a global variable between those tests, and increment it with the proper key when the given test passes.

And the last test should go through this list and check the keys of the tests that passed.

I have read about pytest hooks and pytest cache but the examples that I found were too complicated :(

Someone can help me?
Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure you want to do this? What do you mean by `verify those keys`? You test seems to generate those keys. Can't you verify them inside each test?

Comment: You can add your key variable after your `assert` in each test - this way it won't be added if the test fails. Also I would add a test class that holds this variable to avoid ugly `global` statements. EDIT: Though as @quamrana wrote, you may need to think about what you want to test.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in the `conftest.py` and having a properly scoped fixture. See this [document.](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#scope-sharing-a-fixture-instance-across-tests-in-a-class-module-or-session)

Assuming module scope (essentially all the functions in a file) it could look something like this example:

conftest.py file

```py
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def myfixture():
    keys = []
    yield keys
```

mytests.py

```py
def test_myex1(myfixture):
    myfixture.append(1)
    assert True

def test_myex2(myfixture):
    myfixture.append(2)
    assert True

def test_myex3(myfixture):
    print(myfixture)
    if len(myfixture) == 2:
        assert True
    else:
        assert False
```

Test 3 will pass because, the first test will append keys to `myfixture`. Be careful, because test 3 can't pass independently in this setup.